# How to create a 2D array with N lots of random numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, statistics

I am trying to obtain a variance for a value I obtained by processing a 2x150 array into a discrete correlation function. In order to do this I need to randomly sample 80% of the original data N times, which will allow me to calculate a variance over these values.
 have so far been able to create one randomly sampled set of data using this:

```
rand_indices = []
running_var = (len(find_length)*0.8)
x=0
while x<running_var:
    rand_inx = randint(0, (len(find_length)-1))
    rand_indices.append(rand_inx)
    x=x+1
```

which creates an array 80% of the length of my original with randomly selected indices to be picked out and processed.
My problem is that I am not sure how to iterate this in order to get N sets of these random numbers, I think ideally in a Nx120 sized array. My whole code so far is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from random import randint

useless, just_to, find_length = np.loadtxt("w2_mjy_final.dat").T
w2_dat = np.loadtxt("w2_mjy_final.dat")
w2_rel = np.delete(w2_dat, 2, axis = 1)
w2_array = np.asarray(w2_rel)
w1_dat = np.loadtxt("w1_mjy_final.dat")
w1_rel = np.delete(w1_dat, 2, axis=1)
w1_array = np.asarray(w1_rel)

peaks = []
y=1
N = 0
x = 0
z = 0
rand_indices = []
rand_indices2d = []
running_var = (len(find_length)*0.8)


while z<N:
    while x<running_var:
        rand_inx = randint(0, (len(find_length)-1))
        rand_indices.append(rand_inx)
        x=x+1
    rand_indices2d.append(rand_indices)    
    z=z+1

while y<N:

    w1_sampled = w1_array[rand_indices, :]
    w2_sampled = w2_array[rand_indices, :]

    w1s_t, w1s_dat = zip(*w1_sampled)
    w2s_t, w2s_dat = zip(*w2_sampled)

    w2s_mean = np.mean(w2s_dat)
    w2s_stdev = np.std(w2s_dat)

    w1s_mean = np.mean(w1s_dat)
    w1s_stdev = np.std(w1s_dat)

    taus = []
    dcfs = []
    bins = 40

    for i in w2s_t:
        for j in w1s_t:
            tau_datpoint = i-j
            taus.append(tau_datpoint)


    for k in w2s_dat:
        for l in w1s_dat:
            dcf_datpoint = ((k - w2s_mean)*(l - w1s_mean))/((w2s_stdev*w1s_stdev))
            dcfs.append(dcf_datpoint)     

    plotdat = np.vstack((taus, dcfs)).T
    sort_plotdat = sorted(plotdat, key=lambda x:x[0])  
    np.savetxt("w1sw2sarray.txt", sort_plotdat) 
    taus_sort, dcfs_sort = np.loadtxt("w1w2array.txt").T 
    dcfs_means, taubins_edges, taubins_number = stats.binned_statistic(taus_sort, dcfs_sort, statistic='mean', bins=bins)                               
    taubin_edge = np.delete(taubins_edges, 0)

    import operator
    indexs, values = max(enumerate(dcfs_means), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    percents = values*0.8
    dcf_lists = dcfs_means.tolist()
    centarr_negs, centarr_poss = np.split(dcfs_means, [indexs])
    centind_negs = np.argmin(np.abs(centarr_negs - percents))
    centind_poss = np.argmin(np.abs(centarr_poss - percents))
    lagcent_negs = taubins_edges[centind_negs]
    lagcent_poss = taubins_edges[int((bins/2)+centind_poss)]
    sampled_peak = (np.abs(lagcent_poss - lagcent_negs)/2)+lagcent_negs

    peaks.append(sampled_peak)
    y=y+1 

print peaks
```

Comment: Did you know that instead of the 3 lines: 1) `z = 0` 2) `while z < N:` 3) `z = z + 1` you can do `for z in range(N):`?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're using numpy already, why not use [np.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

In your case:

```
np.random.randint(len(find_length)-1, size=(N, running_var))
```

Would give you an N*running_var sized matrix, with random integer entries from `0` to `len(find_length)-2` inclusive.

**Example Usage:**

```
>>> N=4
>>> running_var=6
>>> find_length = [1,2,3]
>>> np.random.randint(len(find_length)-1, size=(N, running_var))
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Hey cheers for that, I understand what you mean, and it seems a better way to do it but the code given here is resulting in an empty array, output is just [].

Comment: @PatrickScott I've added an example - hopefully that helps you figure it out?